# View Statement on SQL Server returns "Invalid Object Name"

Tags: sql, sql-server

When executing the following script on my SQL Server:

```
CREATE VIEW joiny AS
SELECT EventTime
FROM [dbo].[Table_1]
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid object name 'Table_1'.
```

I cannot figure out why this is an error. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I tried with and without the [] as well as the "dbo".

Comment: what happens when you execute `SELECT EventTime
FROM [dbo].[Table_1]` ?

Comment: Table_1` doesn't exist in the database and schema that you are using

Comment: This would indicate that "Table_1" doesn't exist. Are you sure it does? And in the "dbo" schema?

Comment: The error couldn't get any clearer.  Obviously you don't have this Table_1 that you tried to select.

Comment: I get the same message when I execute. SELECT EventTime FROM [dbo].[Table_1]

Comment: That means you don't have this Table_1

Comment: Or, you don't have the correct database instance set.  Try a USE statement for your database instance of choice. Or include the instance of choice before [dbo].[Table_1].  Such as [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table_1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can mean that the table `[dbo].[Table_1]` simply does not exist in the database you are using.

```
CREATE VIEW tabtest
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.TabTest
```

Results in:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tabtest, Line 4 Invalid object
>   name 'dbo.TabTest'.

Because I do not have a table named `dbo.tabtest` in my database.\

If you are trying to create a view in a different database than the one where your table exists, then you need to use 3-part naming when you specify the table, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW joiny AS
SELECT EventTime
FROM [MyDatabaseName].[dbo].[Table_1]
```

Comment: somehow this works though: 

SELECT TOP (1000) [distance]
      ,[EventTime]
      ,[DeviceId]
  FROM [dbo].[Table_1]

Comment: Probably you are changing the context somehow without realizing it.   So when it works you are in a database where that table exists, and when it doesn't you are in a different database.

Comment: How many query windows you have opened? Both select top 1000 & create view ran in same window? Possibly different connections or target database in different windows..